# Why does the electrostatic potential energy decrease when we connect two charged conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, conductors

When two conducting spherical shells are connected by a conducting wire, electrons replace themselves until the electric potential of both shells is identical, that much is understood. What I don't understand is why does this make as a result that total electrostatic energy of the spherical shells minimized? Is there a physical reason for this result? Meaning, if I take the derivative of the total electrostatic energy with respect to the charge, I get that the charge that minimizes the total energy is the charge we get by equating the electric potentials of both conductors and solving for the charges.

**The math is understood, I'm asking if there is any *physical* insight making it the way it is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, electrons move from one sphere to the other to make their potentials the same. Why? If there exists a potential difference then the charges would move or electric current exists.

> ...why does this make as a result that total electrostatic energy of the spherical shells minimized. Is there a physical reason for this result?

Yes. Nature tends to move towards a state of lower potential energy which is of course more stable than the state with higher potential energy. And thus some initial potential energy is dissipated as heat and the system moves to a lower potential energy.

Comment: Is it analogous to a mass falling to the center of the Earth,  reducing its gravitational potential energy until it hits a floor for example? Could you say it's an intrinsic characteristic of nature, seeking equilibrium?

Comment: @Darkenin: Yes. Almost all systems left to itself, to the best of my knowledge, tend towards lower potential energies which correspond to maximum stability. Another example could be the chemical equivalent of potential energy, the Gibbs free energy -  a compound which has a lower free energy is more stable than the other with higher energy.